# access database is not updating from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

i have a access database named login.mdb,which has many tables.i want to update table named "try".in tat table i have two fields viz name and rollnumber.i want to update rollnum of corresponding name.my code is:

```
Public Class Form11
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Dim MyConnection1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim myCommand1 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim sql As String

    ''# ....

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try

            MyConnection1.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\Documents and Settings\1001\Desktop\Subhedar Sir\WindowsApplication1\bin\login.mdb"

            MyConnection1.Open()
            myCommand1.Connection = MyConnection1

            myCommand1.CommandText = "UPDATE try SET rollnumber = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' WHERE nam = '" & TextBox2.Text & "';"
            myCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            myCommand1.Connection = MyConnection1
            myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("done")

            MyConnection1.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

please tell me where mam going wrong.i am getting error:
system.nullreferenceexception:object refernce not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 2):

On which line do you get your error?

MyConnection1 doesn't look instanciated (could cause it)

; at the end of sql is correct?

Also please try to learn about concept of command parameters. creating sql like this is just plain wrong.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Using MyConnection1 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\Documents and ings\1001\Desktop\Subhedar Sir\WindowsApplication1\bin\login.mdb"), _
            myCommand1 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE try SET rollnumber = @rollnumber WHERE nam = @nam", MyConnection1)

            myCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rollnumber", TextBox1.Text)
            myCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nam", TextBox2.Text)

            MyConnection1.Open()
            myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("done")

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

this should be more like it :)

Comment: Does OleDB support named parameters?

Comment: @Joel Sarcasm?  In case not: Sort of-- you can use the named parameter, but oledb will treat it as a '?'.

Comment: @Lars - No, I don't use OleDb often, and last time I did I had thought it wasn't supported.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Several issues here:

- "Try" is a reserved word in some databases. Access is fine, but if this ever moves it will cause problems. Best to be prepared early.
- No query parameters (vulnerable to sql injection hacks). Try entering `';DROP Table [Try];--` in one of your textboxes with your current code.
- A common db connection for the whole class can cause contention issues and be a bottleneck
- Did not close the connection in a finally block, which will potentially leave connection open and eventually may even cause your database to be unavailable
- Absolute path to the db in the connection string will fail at deployment
- **Never created an instance of the connection object** (that's the error from your exception)

You code should look more like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = login.mdb"), _
          cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [try] SET rollnumber= ? WHERE nam= ? ;", cn)

        ''# Note: I normally don't use AddWithValue(), but I don't know your data types
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox2.Text)

        Try
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("done")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

This code accounts for *all* of the issues listed above, not just the one causing your current exception.

Comment: What was wrong with my code/answer, as I have addressed all (almost) these issues too? Maybe I did not do it in you nice structured way, but information is almost the same, isn't it? OP have never answered anyway.

Comment: @Ales You were missing a line continuation character that would have broken the using statement.  I had started composing mine and had to step away for a while, so I didn't notice yours at first.  I kept mine around because at the time of post I didn't know about your named parameters and because I also enumerate the problems with the original code.

Comment: '_' does not matter in new versions on VB.NET (in many cases. this is one of them) :). But ok :)